# How to display only feautured/sticky listings on the homepage

Tags: posts, sticky-post, featured-post

I want on my homepage on my first page to be displayed only featured listings no matter how old they are

This is my homepage code:

```
   <?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
if(get_option('aven_home') == "listing") { ?>   
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/lib/listhome.php'); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<div id="content">

<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('paged='.$paged);
?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>   

<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<div class="title">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
</div>
<div class="postmeta">
    <span class="author">Posted by <?php the_author(); ?> </span> <span class="clock">  <?php the_time('M - j - Y'); ?></span> <span class="comm"><?php comments_popup_link('0 Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></span>
</div>

<div class="entry">

<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img class="postimg" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php get_image_url(); ?>&amp;h=150&amp;w=200&amp;zc=1" alt=""/></a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img class="postimg" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/dummy.png" alt="" /></a>
<?php } ?>
<?php wpe_excerpt('wpe_excerptlength_index', ''); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php getpagenavi(); ?>

<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>

</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recomend you to use [pre_get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook for your purpose. If you are going to use only the new WP_Query in your theme, it has no sense that Wordpress run a query before it gets your theme becuause it would be a extra work that will be discarded. Using pre_get_posts we can alter the main query to fit our purpose and get what we want without executing another query.

Thats said. Here an example code:

```
//Functions for filters
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'properties_pre_get_post' );
function properties_pre_get_post($query){

    //limit to frontend, to the main query and to home page
   if($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_home() ) {
        //the main query to get only sticky posts
        $query->set('post__in',get_option( 'sticky_posts' ));
    }

}
```

Put that code in functions.php and in your home.php template file you can run [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) as usual.

Custom post types has not support for built-in 'sticky' feature but you can create, for example, a tag or taxonomy term and filter by this tag. For example, if you custom post type support post_tags taxonomy you can created a term called 'featured' and attach each post you want to this tag and filter:

```
//Functions for filters
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_post' );
function my_pre_get_post($query){

     //limit to main query, frontend and home page
     if($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_home() ) {
          $tax_query = array (
                             'taxonomy'=> array('post_tags'),
                             'field'   => 'slug',
                             'terms'   => 'featured',
                             );
          $query->set('tax_query',$tax_query);
          //filter also by your custom post type
          $query->set('post_type','listings');
      } 
}
```

Comment: i don't have the option to make my post stiky. it will work ? The template i am using has a custom taxonomy made listing type and i have 3 option here sold reduce and featured, what i want is the featured to be the first

Comment: Are you using a custom post type?

Comment: yes. the custom post type is called listings

Comment: The custom post types have not sticky feature as normal posts have. You can get a similar functionality adding, for example, a toxonomy term. But then the code I posted have to change to perform a taxonomy query.

Comment: Please, see edited answer

Comment: inserting the code in the function.php and home.php as it is? because if i do that nothing happens .... maybe i insert in the wrong line or something. i am a totally noob

Comment: That code has to be in functions.php but nothing will happen if, as suggested, you don't created a tag called "fearured" and attach to this tag the cutom post you want. You must note also that the code is intended to be used with post_tag taxonomy, which may or may not be supported by your custom post type. If your custom post type dosen't support post_tag taxonomy you will have to use other taxonomy or use other workaround like custom meta fields.